# how to make my array to access in services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

Here i use ionic framework and angularjs, I have a servces  like

```
app.service('MyService',function($scope){
  var value = $scope.product;
  return value;
});
```

and my controller is

```
app.controller("firCtrl",function($scope,$state,MyService){

  $scope.product = ['gopi','dinesh','vasu','prasanth'];
  //MyService.value = $scope.product;
  console.log($scope.product);
    $scope.doClick = function(){
      console.log('invoke');
      $state.go('second');
    };
});
```

my second controller is

```
app.controller("secCtrl",function($scope,MyService){
   $scope.product2 = MyService.value;
});
```

here i have value in my product and this value is displayed in a first page and i have a button in fist page to show the value in product to second page. I'm not getting any idea for viewing my array in list in the second page.

when i use ng-repeat in the first page i am able to display the value and my button but when I click the button i am not able to view the data in the second page

Comment: You want access array created in controller in service?

Comment: yes , so that i can try to view in my second controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you can't inject `$scope` inside service factory function, that is only available in `controller` & directive `link` function.

**Service**

```
app.service('MyService',function(){
  var data = []; //private data
  var self = this;
  //data getter
  self.getData = function(){
    return data;
  }
  //data setter
  self.setData = function(value){
    data = value;
  }
});
```

Then controller will do setData method to set data a sharable

```
MyService.setData($scope.product)
```

And then you could access that shareable data by calling data `getter`

```
app.controller("secCtrl",function($scope,MyService){
    $scope.product2 = MyService.getData();
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer @Pankaj Parkar . Also, $scope can not be inserted in service true

Comment: how am i suppose to view my array in second controller

Comment: @MohanGopi updated my answer..take a look at it.. Thanks :)

Comment: @CoderJohn yupe..and there were couple of things missing, I've also covered them in my answer..

Comment: y do we have this.setData in service

Comment: i mean value in setData

Comment: @MohanGopi short answer is, service does create a new instance of service function.. so you should have your exposed function binded to function context, for long answer I'd recommend to readup on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473)

Comment: @PankajParkar i have add this line MyService.setData($scope.product) in my first controller and when i log my value in service i am getting undefined i think still my array is not set to the data can you help me